# Source for flexibility training

Tags: stretching, flexibility

I want to become more flexible. Unfortunately, there's lots of conflicting and unsourced material on stretching and flexibility training out there.

Could anyone point me to a reputable source for such information? For example a book or website.

Comment: I particularly like Tom Kurz' [*Stretching Scientifically*](http://www.amazon.com/Stretching-Scientifically-Flexibility-Training-Revision/dp/0940149451/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1349789261&sr=1-1&keywords=tom+kurz+stretching).

Comment: It might also help if you explained your goals behind being flexible, if you are trying to correct something, or just general flexibility. Being flexible for soccer, for example, probably wouldn't help much if you are a discus thrower.

Comment: @JohnP I'm after general flexibility, because it would be cool to e.g. sit with a straight back in an acute angle, put my palms to the floor while standing with a straight back, do the split, hand-stand in a split, kick higher, etc. I do practice modern dance and gymnastics, but my goals are wider than that.

Comment: Thanks @DaveLiepmann, I'll see if I can get ahold of a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Try Pavel Tsatsouline "*Relax Into Stretching"* and *Beyond Stretching*. These are good books that will get you flexible in no time.

These books goes through the basics of flexibility. "Relax Into Stretching" goes through the relaxed stretching method which I think Kurz also promotes. It is a safe way of stretching.

"Beyond Stretching" goes through some more advanced techniques like different variations of PNF and some variations of more force-full stretching to get through plateaus.

The first book is a good start to get into stretching for a beginner, and it is good to then get into the other book to increase the results.

Also [Brad Appleton's Stretching FAQ](http://www.bradapp.com/docs/rec/stretching/) is a good resource for stretching.

Comment: Brad Appleton's Stretching FAQ is a good read and contains many details, but there are no figures, and the last update is from 1998 - just sayin'

Comment: The information is just as relevant 1998 as it is today. It is mostly for understanding what you are trying to achieve when stretching though.